# How can i concatinate similar rows in a dataset with matching values of input variables?

Tags: r

Consider input dataset as below:

| Name | age | skills | certificateid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Axon | 23 | java | 123 |
| Axon | 23 | R | 456 |
| Axon | 23 | Python | 789 |
| Angie | 26 | R | 145 |
| Romeo | 30 | R | 786 |
| Romeo | 30 | Python | 093 |

My output should be :

| Name | age | skills | certificateid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Axon | 23,23,23 | java,R,Python | 123,456,789 |
| Angie | 26 | R | 145 |
| Romeo | 30,30 | R,Python | 786,093 |

Can you please provide solution for this rowwise?

Comment: `result<- aggregate(.~Name, data, toString)`

Comment: @Ronak could you please elaborate..This isnt giving me desired output

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: My question is clear ...looks like your aren't aware of this. aggregate() isn't a solution for this